# Cannot add a view not part of the controller in Xamarin storyboard

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a problem with iOS Storyboard Editor under Xamarin.

I want to add a view which is not part of the controller layout as I would do in Xcode dragging a UIView control to the storyboard controller header (added before the 'Exit' icon) but it seems it is not possible in Xamain.

If I add it using Xcode, the storyboard cannot be edited anymore in Xamarin.

Any clue on this?
Is this a limitation in current version of Xamarin or I missed something?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try to open the storyboard with Xamarin? Are you using Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio? I frequently open storyboards with Xcode, make changes, and then open it back in Xamarin Studio. The iOS designer has a lot of limitations compared to Xcode right now (at least there are a lot of things I can't figure out how to accomplish), so what you want to do might not be possible in Xamarin's designer.

Comment: When I open it back in Xamarin Studio, it shows the design but nothing is editable/clickable in the window.

Comment: So I tried this, and it worked out fine. I opened the storyboard with Xcode (from Xamarin Studio), added a UIView by dropping it on Exit, then saved/closed/open w/ XS. The UIView was there in the document outline, and the storyboard worked as usual. Are you on the latest stable release? Can you try with a new project?

Comment: Thanks @DylanS, indeed, after another attempt, things seem to work fine. Just cannot edit the view from Xamarin but it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

If this is anything like I've experienced in the past, you should try flipping the orientation in the storyboard designer and flipping it back.